# Why my blender animation wont render?

Tags: animation

I have the newest version of blender in Linux. I am trying to render a 60 frame animation. I have watched a lot of videos but my promblem is no matter how much i wait it will never render please help me.

Thank you

(Images render normally)

Comment: Have you set output options to animation? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGCsl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGCsl.png)